# Proving this relation given two existing relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have the relations $a^9=b^2=1$ and $a=ba^kb$ for some $k$. I want to prove that $a^{k^2}=a$, but I'm stuck. My computation so far gives: $$a=ba^kb\Rightarrow ab=ba^k\Rightarrow a^{k-1}ab=a^{k-1}ba^k\Rightarrow a=ba^{k-1}ba^k$$

Comment: My advice is to see it as both "$a$ is fixed by conjugation by $b$" and "$b$ has order two, so conjugation by $b$ also has order two". This kind of reasoning will solve most exercices of this type.

Comment: But $a$ *isn't* fixed by conjugation by $b$, this sends $a \mapsto a^k$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $b^2 = 1$, we have as well, from $a = ba^kb$, that $a^k = bab$.

Thus $a^{k^2} = (a^k)^k = (bab)^k = ba^kb = a$.

Answer (score 0):

$a=ba^kb$ so $a=b(ba^kb)^kb=b^2a^kb^2a^kb^2a^k.......a^kb^2=(a^k)^k=a^{k^2}$